# CSS margin left and right

Tags: html, css, gallery

I'm making a Coppermine Theme which is made out of tables (The theme base was made like that). I'm trying to give it a little bit of CSS style.

I want the gallery content to occupy the whole container. [Here you have the link to my gallery](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/copp/).

As you may notice, the gallery content is all over the left, but I can't make it go all over the right too (In that way the whole container will be occupied)

Here you have the CSS code I'm using

```
.maintable {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-left: -40px;
padding-right:50px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<div class="container">` has `padding: 40px` added to it. Try changing that to `padding: 40px 0` to have 40px of vertical padding but no horizontal padding. Remove the `margin-left` and `padding-right` from the `.maintable`

Answer (score 0):

Table cells cannot use margins.

A few alternatives:

1. **Padding.** You can still use padding on table cells.
2. **Add margin to an inner div.** Put a div in your table cell that holds your content and apply margins to that div.
3. **The `border-spacing` property.** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it doing this:   (just comment the lines I've commented below)

**1. Container (style.css:34)**

```
#container {
    width: 1100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    /* padding: 40px; */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 
}
```

**2. menub (style.css:71)**

```
.menub {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    /* width: 100%; */
    padding: 30px;
    /* margin-left: -40px; */
    /* margin-top: -40px; */
    /* padding-right: 50px; */
}
```

**3. adminmenu (style.css:81)**

```
.adminmenu {
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
    color: #fff;
    /* width: 100%; */
    padding: 30px;
    /* margin-left: -40px; */
    /* padding-right: 50px; */
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

**4. maintable (style.css:221)**

```
.maintable {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /* margin-left: -40px; */
    /* padding-right: 50px; */
}
```